# Clipping dataframe based on other columns - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's assume I have the following dataset

```
data = {
  'date': ['1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/3/2019', '1/4/2019', '1/1/2019', '1/2/2019', '1/3/2019', '1/4/2019'],
  'account_id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2],
  'value_1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  'value_2': [1, 3, 6, 9, 10, 12, 14, 16],
    'value_1.1': [5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5],
  'value_2.1': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index = data['date']).drop('date', 1)
df
```

How would I clip col value_1 and value_2 based on the following logic:

--for value_1, upper = value_1.1, lower = None

--for value_2, upper = None, lower = value_2.1?

I was thinking to use sth like this

```
np.where conditions, like np.where(df['value_1']>=value_1.2, value_1, df['value_1'])
```

and

```
np.where(df['value_2']<=value_2.1, 0, df['value_2'])
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: You mentioned clip, then just check with clip https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html

Comment: Are all the values in value_x.1 columns the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use [`pd.DataFrame.clip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html):

```py
df['value1'] = df['value_1'].clip(upper=df['value_1.1'])
df['value2'] = df['value_2'].clip(lower=df['value_2.1'])
```

Comment: `clip` also has an option `inplace=True`.

Comment: I just added df_1 = df.copy() as it was throwing the warning, inplace=True and used @Gustavo's solution. Somehow I thought it would require looping,IFs, etc. Thank you, all, you saved me again.

Answer (score 1):

Since you boundary already a columns in your df , I will do

```
df['value_1']=df.filter(like='value_1').min(1)
df['value_2']=df.filter(like='value_2').max(1)
```